# Change URL after POST using ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I use expressJS as my NodeJS server. The user sends me his login info through a POST and after checking the credentials I render a page:

```
router.post("/login", function (req: Request, res: Response, next) {
   if(credentialsOK){
      res.render('main');
   }
});
```

The problem is that the URL becomes http://myaddress/login and I would like to remove the /login of the address. I don't want to use redirect as I want to send local variables through the render.

How can I change the URL?

Comment: Why don't you use ajax on client to make the request and just use res.json() to send local variables to the client through the ajax calll? Or you want to render 'main' that is something different to what is rendered?

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo main is different from what is rendered

Comment: In that way I think the only way you can do it is by doing all the hard work in the client of rendering what you want to render with the data received from the ajax call, I guess.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can still pass your local variables through `res.redirect`.

```
router.post("/login", function (req: Request, res: Response, next) {
   if(credentialsOK){
       req.session.localVar = yourLocalVar;
       res.redirect('/main');
   }
})
```

Then in `main` router:

```
router.get("/main", function (req: Request, res: Response, next) {
    var yourLocalVar = req.session.localVar;
    res.render('main');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the URL from the server side, but you can change the URL
by using the javascript method `window.history.pushState("", "", '/');`

```
<script>
window.history.pushState("", "", '/');
</script>
```