# render a page in Node and change URL

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, routes, render

I have a login with a form that has the attribute action="api/login", after loging in, it renders a page and shows a pathname of http://localhost:3000/api/login.  I want it to say http://localhost:3000/dashboard.  I tried redirecting /dashboard then rendering, but I just got a blank page.  Below is my code. I am using NodeJS, I have a route folder that calls to the Auth Controller.

```
//html form
<form method='post' action="api/login">

//route
router
    .route('/login')
    .post(ctrlAuth.login); 



module.exports.login = function(req, res) {

////DOES AUTH CODE STUFF here//////

                        res
                            .status(200)
                            .render('holder', {
                                device: req.session.device,
                                id: req.session.id,
                                first_name: req.session.first_name,
                                last_name: req.session.last_name,
                                role: req.session.role,
                                users: user_data
                            });
                    })

                })



            } else {
                console.log('password incorrect')
                res.redirect('/home')
            }
        });
    })

};
```

Comment: you can add `res.send({redirect: '/dashboard'});` after you login, this should redirect to dashboard

Comment: thanks, i got it to work

Comment: I m pasting the answer please mark it correct so other people looking for the same should get it

Comment: What you are looking for is available at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425926/change-url-after-post-using-expressjs/45633936#45633936

Comment: What you are looking for is available at this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425926/change-url-after-post-using-expressjs/45633936#45633936

Answer (score 1):

you can add `res.send({redirect: '/dashboard'});` after you login, this should redirect to dashboard